# maven-assembly-plugin generates tar incompatible with python's tarfile (works with bsdtar)

Tags: python, maven, tar, maven-assembly-plugin, tarfile

As part of an automated deployment pipeline I'm creating a `tar.gz` file with the `maven-assembly-plugin` then unpacking it with python's `tarfile` module.

The extraction fails with the exception:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tarfile-assembly-testcase/extract_tar.py", line 20, in <module>
    tarfile.open(fileobj=f, mode='r:gz')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1676, in open
    return func(name, filemode, fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1725, in gzopen
    **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1703, in taropen
    return cls(name, mode, fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1572, in __init__
    self.firstmember = self.next()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2335, in next
    raise ReadError(str(e))
ReadError: invalid header`

That happens with both compressed and uncompressed tar files. The same file can be unpacked from command line. I've tested it with `bsdtar 2.8.3` and `tar (GNU tar) 1.26`. I'm using `python 2.7`.

Please try the [demo](https://github.com/spaceCamel/tarfile-assembly-testcase) I published on github. It's a maven project, running mvn package it will creates a tar.gz containing the souce of the project (only the pom.xml). The python script included tries to extract it using `tarfile`.

Any idea to make `maven-assembly-plugin` and python's `tarfile` play well together?

Comment: Which version of the tar module in python do you use (found an old [bug for py module](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2011-July/608865.html)? Why not filed in a [bug in jira for the maven-assembly-plugin](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY).

Comment: Has already been done. http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/PLXCOMP-233

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem. Copying the solution I found [here (see "Version pinning" paragraph)](http://www.misanthropicgeek.net/?p=1303) in Stackoverflow for future generations.

The `maven-assembly-plugin` as of version 2.4 imports a buggy version of `plexus-archiver`. Forcing the `maven-assembly-plugin` to use the latest `plexus-archiver` did the trick. As suggested in the linked post I also upgraded `plexus-io`.

Here is the code

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-archiver</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Do you need both of them or only one of them? For 2.5 of maven-assembly-plugin the plexus-archiver will be newer.